# Playscape SDK developer build fails

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

When we try to build developer build version for Android(requested by playscape representative) via Unity 4.6.8f1, it fails at the stage of Applying Post-Build Logic with the following message:

[image]

Same app, but without Playscape SDK builds fine in Developer Mode.
We're using Playscape SDK 1.14. So how should we provide a developer build?

Comment: did you provide keystore in unity. under player settings->android->publishing settings

Comment: yes. we have valid keystore, which is working in release build, but doesn't work in debug with playscape SDK. we also tried User/.android/debug.keystore and unsigned build, resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved with playscape SDK 1.16